# How prevent connecting Farsi Characters?

Tags: html, css, persian, farsi

I have a problem, but maybe this is not a problem actually! Why below HTML markup is generating a result which seems to be incorrect even using Standard Fonts like Arial?

```
<span>سلام</span><span>خداحافظ</span>
```

سلامخداحافظ

Above output shouldn't be this? (ignore space used for simulation)

سلام خداحافظ

Also i have used margin for a tag but same problem.
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: The only difference I see between your two examples is the space and that the character behind it looks `p` like in the second and latin `s` like in the first. What difference are you talking about?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, questioner wants the [meem](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/645/index.htm) character to keep its [final form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Letter_forms) instead of switching to its medial form.

Comment: Thanks Frederic to clarify what's my issue ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML elements do not necessarily break words. There are many legitimate reasons for that.

For instance, you might want to put emphasis on a letter in medial form by wrapping it in a `<strong>` or `<em>` element. If that element was considered as a single word, the letter would switch to its isolated form, which would probably not be the effect you're looking for.

Inserting either a [non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm) (`&nbsp;`) or a [zero-width non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) (`&#8203;`) between the `<span>` elements fixes your problem.

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHr4E/).

Comment: Thank you for describing **Legitimate Reason** of this behavior!

Answer (score 1):

As i know `span tag` doesnt have `href`. I assume that u mean `a tag`.

u can use a space character between `a tags` to get desired result:

```
<a href="#">سلام</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">خداحافظ</a>
```

Comment: Oppps! That was my mistake. I used span to better clarify issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enter a space between the two tags like this. There is no need to use HTML codes:

```
<a href="#">سلام</a> <a href="#">خداحافظ</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

with this HTML:

```html
<a href="#">سلام</a>
<a href="#">خداحافظ</a>
```